# omines/datatables bundle wont search datetime columns

Tags: symfony, datatables

im using a bundle to render a datatable grid, the bundle its called omines/datatables-bundle. The search performs correctly for all fields except for the filledAt column which is a DateTimeColumn one, this type is defined by the Omines guys.
This is the code of my action:

```
public function index(Request $request, CarRepository $carRepository, DataTableFactory $dataTableFactory)
    {
        $table = $dataTableFactory->create()
            ->add('id', NumberColumn::class, ["orderable" => true, "searchable" => true])
            ->add('carBrand', TextColumn::class, ["field" => "brand.name", "orderable" => true, "label" => "Marca del Carro", "searchable" => true])
            ->add('model', TextColumn::class, ["field" => "car.model", "orderable" => true, "label" => "Modelo del Carro", "searchable" => true])
            ->add("filledAt", DateTimeColumn::class, ["format" => "Y-m-d H:i:s", "searchable" => true, "orderable" => true])
            ->add("fuelFilled", NumberColumn::class, ["render" => "%s L", "searchable" => true])
            ->add("price", NumberColumn::class, ["render" => "%s cuc", "searchable" => true])
            ->add("formerRead", NumberColumn::class, ["searchable" => true])
            ->add("currentRead", NumberColumn::class, ["searchable" => true])
            ->add("mileage", NumberColumn::class, ["searchable" => true])
            ->add('actions', TwigColumn::class, [
                'className' => 'buttons',
                'template' => 'frontend/supervisor/carfill/table-buttons.html.twig',
            ])
            ->addOrderBy('filledAt', DataTable::SORT_DESCENDING)
            ->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
                "entity" => CarFuelFillRecord::class,
                "query" => function(QueryBuilder $builder){
                    $builder
                        ->from("App:CarFuelFillRecord", "cffr")
                        ->select("cffr, car, brand")
                        ->leftJoin("cffr.car", "car")
                        ->leftJoin("car.brand", "brand")
                    ;
                }
            ])
            ->handleRequest($request);

        if ($table->isCallback()) {
            return $table->getResponse();
        }

        return $this->render('frontend/supervisor/carfill/index.html.twig', [
            'datatable' => $table,
            "cars" => $carRepository->findAll()
        ]);
    }
```

This is the code of my template

```
<script>
$(function() { $('#carFuelFillRecords').initDataTables({{ datatable_settings(datatable) }},{searching: true}); });
</script>
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is due to the difference between your date format and the format the date is stored in the database. The bundle seems to search exactly for the entered string, which is in your case probably in the format "Y-m-d H:i:s", but in the database not. So it doesn't find the date you entered.